# When do ARMA models fail?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have just started learning about Autoregressive–moving-average model (ARMA). On the Wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model), it has been mentioned that:

> ARMA is appropriate when a system is a function of a series of
> unobserved shocks (the MA or moving average part) as well as its own
> behavior. For example, stock prices may be shocked by fundamental
> information as well as exhibiting technical trending and
> mean-reversion effects due to market participants.

I would like to know what are the worst cases for ARMA models i.e. when one should definitely not use it. For example, if I want to use an ARMA model to forecast the value of sign wave, should it perform really bad since there are no shocks?